# Running Ignite on Swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, ignite

I'm trying to run apacheignite/ignite image on a swarm cluster.
When I scale the ignite service, nodes do not discover each others.

Here is my stack.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  ignite:
    image: apacheignite/ignite
    dns: 172.26.80.129
    environment:
      - "CONFIG_URI=http://myserver.mycompany.com/ignite/config.xml"
    networks:
      - ignite-net
networks:
  ignite-net:
    driver: overlay
```

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="localPort" value="15900"/>
            <property name="localPortRange" value="79"/>
            <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                <property name="addresses">
                    <list>
                        <value>ignite:15900..15979</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why this down vote? If I knew, I could improve my future questions ...

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use Multicast discovery in order for them to find each other without listing addresses. `org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder`

Alternatively you should list all (or at least a few) of addresses:

```
            <property name="addresses">
                <list>
                    <value>node1.ignite:15900..15979</value>
                    <value>node2.ignite:15900..15979</value>
                    ...
                </list>
            </property>
```

Note that these host names should be resolvable by all nodes. It's often easier to use IP addresses.

Then again, there's a [huge number of ways to do discovery](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config) in documentation.

The last one is, using VM discovery, Ignite has a mode where hosts are passed via environment variable. To use it, you should probably remove `addresses` property altogether. And populate `IGNITE_TCP_DISCOVERY_ADDRESSES` env var with addresses of other nodes (or at least one common). Comma separated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, multicast in swarm does not work across different hosts in overlay networks. In my (big) company, swarm nodes and their IP addresses may change frequently. Using node names (or ip) in my stack will probably creates a lot of problems.

Comment: @Jean-MarcAstesana for such deployments, Ignite has a mode where hosts are passed via environment variable. To use it, you should probably remove "addresses" property altogether (using VM discovery). And populate `IGNITE_TCP_DISCOVERY_ADDRESSES` env var with addresses of other nodes (or at least one common).

Comment: I agree, a huge number of ways to discovery. Unfortunately, the one in the example in "https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/docker-deployment" (multicast) does not work. I still not really understand why what I've posted in my question does not work (probably an obvious error in my stack), but I will check others and post a working solution if I succeed.

Comment: @Jean-MarcAstesana the obvious problem in your example is this line: `<value>ignite:15900..15979</value>`. It should list at least one node reachable from all other nodes in cluster. Does `ignite` hostname resolve? To what?

Comment: In an swarm cluster, the name of a service resolves to one of the containers running the service. So when the service is first instantiated, 'ignite' resolves to the container. When the service is scaled up, this name resolved to one of the containers (Round robin DNS). Maybe, this is the problem, as the second container, when it resolves the 'service' could get itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution.
I added a client service that uses the Ignite cluster to make it a more realistic example.

I did not understand what was the problem in my initial post, but this is working. When ignite service is scaled, client see all Ignite nodes (including the ignite-master).

**Warning: Not to be used for production.** The ignite-master container is a single point of failure. Scaling up or down this service results in a whole cluster failure.

stack.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  tomcat-client:
    image: me/myimage.ws
    depends_on:
      - ignite-master
    ports:
      - "15280:8080" 
    networks:
      - ignite-test-net
    environment:
      - CONFIG_URI=http://myserver.mycompany.com/ignite/config.xml
  ignite:
    image: apacheignite/ignite
    depends_on:
      - ignite-master
    environment:
      - "CONFIG_URI=http://myserver.mycompany.com/ignite/config.xml"
    networks:
      - ignite-test-net
  ignite-master:
    image: apacheignite/ignite
    environment:
      - "CONFIG_URI=http://myserver.mycompany.com/ignite/config.xml"
    networks:
      - ignite-test-net
networks:
  ignite-test-net:
    driver: overlay
```

And the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                <property name="addresses">
                    <list>
                        <value>ignite-master</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Multicast discovery does not work in a Docker swarm cluster but for a small number of ignite nodes you could use the following stack file snippet:

```
ignite:
 image: apacheignite/ignite
 hostname: node-{{ .Task.Slot }}
 deploy:
   replicas: 8
```

Set the hostname manually by using the template placeholder for `Task.Slot`.
This has the effect that 8 service tasks are created in your stack, reachable within the cluster by their hostnames `node-1`, `node-2`, ..., `node-8`.
You can use all or some of these hostnames for your Iginite configuration file.

This solution does not replace a production grade node discovery (as possible with Zookeeper, Consul, etc.) but however allows some flexibility in small Docker based Ignite environments.